# Is there an easy way to perform CI with native C++ code (VS2010) and Bamboo?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, continuous-integration, bamboo

We're using JIRA with Bamboo as build server for continuous integration.
But I have a native C++ project (using Visual Studio 2010), and apparently Microsoft doesn't support unit tests for native C++ code. There's some tools like WinUnit or cfix that seem to do the job, but neither do I know about their compatibility to Bamboo, nor do I know which tool is the best / easiest to use / has the most features / has best VS compatibility ...

Does someone have experience with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played a bit with CppUnit. The way it works is that you create an executable project which you fill with your test cases. When run, it runs your tests. I think cfix does that but I've never used it for user mode testing. To run the tests as part of your build process, put in a post build step for your test project that runs the test exe. It'll run when you build your Visual Studio solution.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a heads up, my current project is using c++ with bamboo for CI.  We use googletest for our testing framework.  If you have the build run with --gtest_output=xml:{file or Directory} it will produce xml output that can parsed by Bamboo's JUnit Parse task.